# Flink: Is it possible to have two ordered outputs?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, etl, pipeline

**Despite concepts**, it is possible to have two ordered outputs for unique stream/environment flow using Flink? Ex. Extract -> Transform -> 1. Load to Table API [table insert query] && 2. Sink a message [KafkaProducer]?

If not, what do you suggest for a better approach?

Comment: What do you mean be order? Can you update your question to include an example and why you think the concepts are not working in your favor?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I mean, execution "order", like: for every streaming It must execute two sinks in order. Always execute Table API first and, then, a Kafka producer. BUT kafka producer uses the same input as Table API...

Well, I changed the approach and used RichSinkFunction instead of Table API. It seems to be working properly.